# Show that if ab ≡ ac (mod n) and d = (a, n), then b ≡ c (mod n/d)

Tags: number-theory

So right now I have that since $d = (a, n)$ then $a=ds$ and $n=dt$ for some integers $s$ and $t$.

Then we can write $ab ≡ ac \mod n ⇒ (ds)b ≡ (ds)c\mod dt ⇒ sb ≡ sc \mod t$.

And then I'm stuck. Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

$ab\equiv ac \bmod n$
so $(ab-ac)$ is divisible by $n$, that is $a(b-c) = kn$

So now using your $a=ds$ and $n=dt$, we can see that $s(b-c) = kt$
But we also know that $s$ and $t$ have no common factors, meaning that $t \mid (b-c)$
Thus $(b-c)=mt$ and so $\fbox{$b\equiv c \bmod t$}$ (and of course $t=\frac{\large n}{\large d}$)

Comment: The final step invokes Euclid's lemma in case it's not familiar.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see it now!

Comment: Nice solution..